# Change picture according to language selection

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

Is it possible to change an imageView depending on the language selection of the mobile?

This is the code that I am using in xml, what I want is if there is a way that when it is in a certain language the image will change to the corresponding language because there is text entered in the images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/calculate_wavelength_stepversion"
        android:id="@+id/imageExample"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/desarrollo"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageExample"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


   </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not too sure on what you need, but try this link out: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create like this, res/drawable-en-rCA/ or res/drawable-fr-rCA/, You can refer [AliasResources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)

Answer (score 0):

Use some logic in your java class, when you detect a certain language change, set the content of the image to a different drawable.